# hoverintent.js with slideToggle

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I have a navigation menu with the following markup:

```
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="url/page">Parent</a>
        <ul class="main-nav-child">
            <li><a href="url/page">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="url/page">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="url/page">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using `slideToggle` to hide/show the child UL: `ul.main-nav-child`, like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.main-nav-child').hide();
    $('.main-nav > li').hover(function () {
        $('ul', this).slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

I'm trying to make it work with the hoverintent.js plugin, after reviewing the examples given [here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/hoverintent/), I'm still at a dead end making it work.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$('.main-nav > li').hover(function(){
        $('ul', this).doTimeout( 'slideToggle', 250 );
    }, function(){
        $('ul', this).doTimeout( 'slideToggle', 250 );
});
```

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hypzo/kwcj8b40/)***

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.main-nav-child').hide();
    $('.main-nav > li').hover(function(){
        $(this).doTimeout( 'hover', 250, function() {
            $('.main-nav-child').slideToggle(250);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That certainly solves my example problem above, thank you! One small caveat: When there's multiple parent <li> items all the child <ul> elements are toggled at once (I should have made this clear in my question, apologies), as a guess I'd say I'd need `this` somewhere along the way, could i possibly (and gratefully) ask for your assistance again?

Comment: Would you please post an example of what you mean= you can build on my fiddle to explain the problem

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/kwcj8b40/4/, when you hover on `.main-nav li` all child ul's open, I'd like only the child ul of the parent being hovered on, if that make sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: However I have a feeling you are looking for something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hypzo/kwcj8b40/6/